# Extension of a compact set via continuous functions

Tags: compactness, inverse-function

Define a set $\mathcal{D}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a continuously differentiable function $h:\mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the set
$\mathcal{C} = \{ x \in \mathcal{D} : h(x) \geq 0\}$. Let $h$ be defined on $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{D}$, and is compact.

Now consider the following set:
$$
\mathcal{C}_e = \{ x \in \mathcal{D} : h(x) \geq - \epsilon \} \subset \mathcal{D},
$$
for some $\epsilon >0$.

What can we say about $\mathcal{C}_e$. Is it compact as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Here is a counter example.

[Counter example for the compactness arguement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxSaY.png)

Comment: You get obvious counter-examples  with $\mathcal C$ is empty.

Comment: Excellent point, empty set is compact as well.

Answer (score 0):

$C_e$ is closed since it is the primage of $h^{-1}[\epsilon,\infty)$ and a closed subset of a compact set is again compact (in this case, since it is bounded.)

Comment: I see. The set is $h^{-1}([-\epsilon,\infty))$, which is closed.
$$
h^{-1}([-\epsilon,\infty)) = h^{-1}([-\epsilon,0]) \cup h^{-1}([0,\infty))
                                     = h^{-1}([-\epsilon,0]) \cup \mathcal{C}
$$